# Windows forms resize

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have created a form in Visual Studio 2010 and set its size property to 1280x800. I want its contents (four pictureboxes) to fill exactly this screen resolution. It works fine in my development computer when I change the resolution (from 1920x1080 to 1280x800) to test, but when I deploy at the client's laptop it messes everything up. Basically it makes all the controls smaller.

Both computers run Windows 7. I do not want anything to resize, I want exactly the size I specify for everything.

How do I prevent the form contents from resizing? Why is this happening and how can I test for this behavior in my production PC?

Comment: Also check with the client if they are using a different DPI setting (http://www.lawfirmsoftware.com/support/change_dpi_settings_xp.htm). That messes things up badly.

Comment: If the form only contains picture boxes, not any control that displays text then set the form's AutoScaleMode property to None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the DPI setting that messed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx#Y0) property of the Picturebox controls to fix correctly to the window in your application. Which will resize the pictureboxes also when you resize the window.